# If the glideslope signal is higher than it should be, can I continue the approach?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, ils

When I'm passing Precision Final Approach Fix, if my glideslope is two dot above, and my altitude is at PFAF altitude, can I continue my approach with this glideslope signal?

Is it legal? I think the glideslope indication is not correct with charted PFAF altitude, so I MUST execute missed approach because I can determine that I'm now receiving false glideslope indication.

What statement can I apply in this situation?

[image]

Comment: What about flying to Localizer-only minimums until you reach the Localizer MAP and going missed from there?

Answer (score 1):

You should continue the approach.  The altitude listed on the PFAF is for standard atmospheric conditions.

We can adjust the barometric altimeter for non-standard pressure using the Kollsman window.

We cannot adjust the barometric altimeter for warmer or colder than standard conditions.  In cold weather, you will intercept the GS inside the point listed on as the FAF for the localizer.  In warmer weather, you will intercept the GS outside the point listed on the localizer.

Due to this issue, the FAA issued a InFO to address pilots who go below MEAs on warmer than standard days.

https://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/airline_operators/airline_safety/info/all_infos/media/2011/InFO11009.pdf

Comment: Thx for your answer, too, however this question was not for that point, and I wrote about this above.

Comment: If you are at 2,100 FT MSL on a cold day (below -20° C), you may find the GS at full scale deflection crossing ZENZA inbound.  Due to the errors in the altimeter, this is a normal indication.  The GS will intercept at 5.3 NM instead of 5.9 NM.  False glideslope indications are much higher than these.  A 6° false slope crosses ZENZA at 3,800 FT and provides "reverse sensing".  A 9° false slope crosses ZENZA at 5,753 FT MSL with "positive sensing".

Answer (score 1):

The temperature related "Indicated" altitude issue pointed out in the answer by @wbeard52 is an important consideration for position awareness.  But when flying an ILS (following the GS), unless there is a step-down fix crossing altitude involved, a temperature/indicated altitude issue is not involved.

However, also ensure that you understand that the FAF for an ILS is not the same point as for a Localizer approach (Maltese Cross symbol).  The FAF for an ILS approach is the point at which the Glide Slope is intercepted at the published "Glide Slope Intercept" altitude.  This point is shown by the lightening bolt symbol.  See the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Thx for your kindness and detailed answer,
However, my question was not that point.
When I shot an approach in FTD, when I arrived at PFAF(which is determined by glideslope intercept below glideslope intercept altutide) DME Distance, I was at Glideslope intercept altitude, however my glideslope indicator was "two" dot above.

And, when I tried to follow that signal to DA, I already passed the runway.
I think this is related to specific FTD problem, but.. if I face this situation in real world, what should I do?

Comment: Can I continue my approach with this false signal without any further reports to ATC or anything else that I can do in this situation?

Comment: And, if I can continue my approach, where should I decide to abort my ILS approach or execute missed approach?
I think decision at DA is too late because if I follow that false indication to DA, my airplane even go further than the airport as I mentioned.
And I think decision point is at OM or FAF instead of OM.

Comment: @moon: if it was me, as soon as I discovered that there was a problem with the ILS approach I would advise ATC and request a radar vector for an approach other than an ILS. Since you can't identify the MAP without a functioning GS (DA on the GS  is the MAP).

Comment: So.. you mean when you arrive at the distance that the glideslope intercept altitude is set, if your glideslope is not centered, you decide to request radar vectors?
In conclusion, can I use glideslope intercept altitude and DME specified in charts if that chart has PFAF with altitude and DME distance to determine whether or not glideslope is reliable?

Comment: @moon: I would need to see the specific ILS approach that you are talking about in order to respond.  I have never seen an ILS approach that has a DME fix exactly at the GS Intercept altitude unless the GS Intercept altitude point was at the same point as the Localizer FAF (Maltese Cross/DME fix). But if I suspected that the approach guidance may be inaccurate I would advise ATC and request a different approach or other alternative action.

Comment: Thanks for your help! The airport that I've questioned has ILS ONLY Approach and it has PFAF, which is shown as lightning bolt on profile view.
I attached a chart and I found that the symbol like at FAF ZENZA is Lightning bolt in our country

Comment: @moon: in the ILS approach you posted your obligation is to cross ZENGA at or above 2100 ft. indicated altitude.  If it is cold or hot above/below the standard atmosphere you will be at a different "true" altitude at ZENGA and not precisely centered on the GS. Read the information in Wbeard's answer for more information on how temperature affects Indicated altitude.

Comment: You are talking about the ILS Y RWY 24R at RKTU.  If you descend to 2100' MSL after passing 8.0 DME and intercept the GS (either before or after ZENZA) you will be on the correct glideslope.  Falso glideslopes are multiples of 3° above the correct one.  So, there is a false glideslope is at 6° and 9° and 12°.

Comment: Full scale deflection of the glideslope at a 5NM distance is 186'.  If you are on the correct altitude (2,100' MSL) when you capture the glideslope you will be on the correct glideslope and not a false glideslope.  It is this reason why we always intercept the glideslope from below and not above.  To ensure we capture the correct one.